# Android Volley string request cannot get response

Tags: android, android-volley

Hello fellow developers,

I have just made a trial version for my app which use volley to communication with my PHP server. However, one of my friends told me that his phone(Asus Zenfone 2) get stuck whenever he submit a request, while other phones perform perfectly. In fact, the request submitted is actually reach the server and the server response normally. That's why I suspect that his phone can't catch back the response...

I have tried to run his phone under android monitor, no specific error log is noted.Below are the only error logs occur, not sure if it's related.

05-23 21:04:20.916 304-620/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'INTERFACE' not found
05-23 21:04:20.916 304-620/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
05-23 21:04:20.916 632-668/? E/NetdConnector: Error handling '613 IfaceClass active (null)': java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "(null)"

I am continuing testing on his phone. If you have the same experience or any clue on this fail case, please feel free to share with me ;)

Comment: enable volley logging and paste the logs please: adb shell setprop log.tag.Volley VERBOSE

Comment: @djodjo Thanks so much for your advice! I got this log:
BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]  0xf71ce8e8 NORMAL 3> [lifetime=3069], [size=74], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
It seems to be a slow network problem, I am working on optimising the volley request and make a better handle on no/slow network situation.